# Как чистить оперативную память сервера после выполнения php скрипта?

Tags: php, linux, сервер, веб-сервер, memory

Проблема собственно вот в чем: мои скрипты php после отработки засоряют оперативную память сервера,но не все конечно. Системный администратор после изучения этой темы говорит что память засоряется после моих скриптов и они являются активными процессами( как я понял спящими по букве S)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Я прекрасно понимаю, что вы не волшебники и не можете проинтуичить без выкладки кода, но может кто то сталкивался с подобными проблемами. Хотелось бы понять алгоритм нахождения ответа. Может он заключается в том чтобы прозвонить код на количество резервируемой под него памяти, найти самый прожорливый участок и оптимизировать его.

Даже если это будет выполнено, памяти будет жрать меньше, но причина похоже не в этом. Может необходимо найти конфигурационный файл сервера и обратить внимание на конкретные строки параметров? В зависимости от ситуации я добавлю сюда необходимую информацию

Или может добавлять какуюто строку кода в php скрипт чтобы сервер убивал соединение?

Да кстати в циклах использую

```
break;
```

Также использовал

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
```

Но после закоменчивания этой строки изменений не было. Или может жестко поступить - найти все переменные и сделать

```
unset($some_param);
```

Откуда начинать копать? Статьи по оптимизации кода читал, применяю их на практике, но как известно в этом направлении можно далеко уйти и писать на Ассемблере

Добавлено минутой позже:

Также использую в коде

```
exit();
```

в том случае если код не имеет смысла дальше выполнять - или вместо него необходимо использовать

```
die();
```

Добавлено 5 минутами позже:

Это веб сервер.
Пользователь загружает фаил эксель для парсинга и получается вышеописанное
NGINX 1.6.2 PHP5-FPM без APACHE
5.6 PHP версия

Добавлено через 9 часов:

на [форуме](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36195/how-to-know-reason-of-a-process-going-to-sleep-state-and-wake-it-up) говорится о команде

```
strace -p <pid>
```

которая показывает что хочет выполнить процесс в нашем случае PID 10354. Это конечно не ответ на вопрос, но может поспособствовать его решению.

На [ресурсе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853845/in-nix-what-causes-sleeping-in-top-command) сказано что данный режим может быть вызван недостатком мощностей процессора(но по сути какой бы мощный процессор не был, нагрузить его на 100% можно), также сказано что такое поведение наблюдается когда в коде php есть команда

```
sleep($count_of_seconds);
```

Да - данная команда ввергает процесс в состояние Sleep, но здесь нет зависимости от количества потребляемой памяти.

Как мне объяснил системный администратор - сколько пользователей на сайте, столько будет спящих www-data, следовательно состояние sleep вполне нормально, ненормально количество удерживаемой для этого процесса памяти.

Добавлено 22,02,2017

Вот что происходит когда остаются 3 спящих процесса

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: с версии 5.3 PHP имеет [Garbage Collection](http://php.net/manual/ru/features.gc.performance-considerations.php) - по идее gc отвечает за очистку неиспользуемой памяти. какая у вас версия php ?

Comment: Интересно почему выши скрипты остаются в процессах если вы говорите что они закончили работу. Надо смотреть в сторону того кто их запускает. Если это web-сервер, то в зависимости от настроек сервера он может оставлять скрипты в памяти что бы при следующем запросе не надо было запускать их заново. И в принципе это нормальная практика она ускоряет открытие страниц

Comment: тогда смотрите настройки этого web-сервера и/или в вопросе укажите что за сервер и каковы эти настройки.

Comment: настроек море - какие именно необходимо смотреть? NGINX 1.6.2
PHP5-FPM без APACHE

Comment: "в зависимости от настроек сервера он может оставлять скрипты в памяти что бы при следующем запросе не надо было запускать их заново" - вот это и интересно - там библиотека и исполняемые скрипты максимум на 30 Mb

Comment: Он не отработал, он куда-то пишет/откуда-то читает и в состоянии S ждет ответа

Comment: @etki укажите пожалуйста источник информации, в котором есть данные об этом состоянии S и какой ответ может ожидаться?

Comment: https://www.google.ru/search?q=linux+process+states https://access.redhat.com/sites/default/files/attachments/processstates_20120831.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут оказывается не только дело в скриптах но и в настройках php-fpm а именно надо поиграться с настройками

/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
а именно

```
pm.max_requests
request_terminate_timeout
```

**request_terminate_timeout** устанавливает максимальное время выполнения дочернего процесса, прежде чем он будет уничтожен. Это позволяет избегать долгих запросов, если по какой-либо причине было изменено значение max_execution_time в настройках интерпретатора. Значение стоит установить исходя из логики обрабатываемых приложений, скажем 60s (1 минута).

Answer (score 2):

Моя история похожа.
Конфигурация: *nginx+php-fpm*

Тяжелый запрос на бекенде и при заходе на него 3-5 раз подряд, память забивалась и вылетала ошибка:

> 502 bad gateway

При этом память сама не отчищалась.

Мой конфиг до проблемы:

- pm = dynamic
- pm.max_children = 50
- pm.start_servers = 5
- pm.min_spare_servers = 5
- pm.max_spare_servers = 25
- pm.max_requests = 500

Конфиг после:

- pm = dynamic
- pm.max_children = 10
- pm.start_servers = 3
- pm.min_spare_servers = 2
- pm.max_spare_servers = 5
- pm.max_requests = 500

Попробуйте так.

Answer (score 1):

Считаю 374 мегабайта RES совершенно нормальным значением для php-fpm.

То есть, на мой взгляд, у вас проблема совершенно не в вашем коде, а либо в использовании PHP как такового, либо просто в неадекватной задачам конфигурации сервера (мало RAM для запущенного набора процессов).

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста какая информация скрывается за фразой  "проблема в использовании PHP как такового" и "проблема в неадекватной к задачам конфигурации сервера" - задача в том чтобы сервак после выполнения скрипта(не из консоли) подчищал за собой память - кстати попробую выполнить из консоли и расскажу есть ли различия,

Comment: PHP - не тот язык, от интерпретатора которого сто́ит ожидать, что он будет экономить память. Это ответ на первый вопрос.
400 мегабайт - это немного. Если для вашего сервера это много, и требуются какие-то специальные меры по очистке памяти, то, возможно, вы взяли не ту машину в качестве сервера. Это ответ на второй вопрос.

Используйте CGI, если хотите полного завершения процессов-обработчиков. Причем не FastCGI и не uwSGI, то есть не nginx, а apache.

Comment: Если по вашему мнению данная машина не способна справится с поставленной задачей, то позвольте узнать - какая информация на это указывает? Какие темы гуглить? Вернее машина справляется с любой поставленной задачей на скриптах php. Проблема в том, что если несколько клиентов откроют функционал с зарезервированной памятью - это может замусорить всю память и занять SWAP, а это уже чревато серьезными тормозами.